# Making a panel pop up when a dropdown option is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I already have a dropdown menu made. I want to make it to where, when you click an item in the dropdown menu a panel pops up (Panels were already made). So how would I create that? Here is my current code.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
          <label>Label</label>
           <select onchange="jsFunction()">
           <option value="blank"></option>
             <optgroup label="Label">
               <option value="Item #1">Item #1</option>
               <option value="Item #2">Item #2</option>
               <option value="Item #3">Item #3</option>
             </optgroup>
             <optgroup label="Label">
               <option value="Item #4">Item #4</option>
               <option value="Item #5">Item #5</option>
               <option value="Item #6">Item #6</option>
               <option value="Item #7">Item #7</option>
             </optgroup>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: The "pop up" panel text differs depending on what was clicked in the drop down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in this [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/r0fjf017/)

```js
var popup = $('#popup'),
  select = $('#slct');
$('#popup #close').on('click', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  popup.hide();
});

select.on('change', function() {
  popup.show();
});
```

```css
#popup {
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  display: block;
  background: #CFCFCF;
  left: calc(50% - 175px);
  top: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  cursor: default;
  display: none;
}
#popup h3 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <label>Label</label>
    <select id="slct">
      <option value="blank"></option>
      <optgroup label="Label">
        <option value="Item #1">Item #1</option>
        <option value="Item #2">Item #2</option>
        <option value="Item #3">Item #3</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="Label">
        <option value="Item #4">Item #4</option>
        <option value="Item #5">Item #5</option>
        <option value="Item #6">Item #6</option>
        <option value="Item #7">Item #7</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="popup">
  <h3>Pop Up Title</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  <a id="close" href="">close</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The panel does differ between what is clicked. Sorry for the late response.

Comment: It's ok, do you need more help with that?

Comment: I havnt tested it yet because I dont have the file with me. But will I be able to make multiple different pop ups with this?

Comment: Sorry if I am being stupid, I am really tired at the moment.

Comment: Sure, there are more than one way to do this, easiest one is to have several *hidden* divs each one contains text you need if the corresponding option from the drop down, when you click that option, you inject that div's text into the popup panel

Comment: another way is to have more than one popup panel each one with different text and with each option from the drop down you hide all popups and then show only the wanted one, but the first solution is better in my opinion